# Is there a way to setup lombok using pom.xml?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, lombok

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

[lombok setup for eclipse](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse)

I want to avoid the above steps. Is it possible to setup lombok by itselt when I open the project in STS or Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 1):

No, Eclipse wouldn't recognize anything that lombok is doing for you <strike>adds at runtime</strike> while you're inside of Eclipse.